# Error while preparing Solr index offline using MapReduceIndexerTool of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, solr

I am executing `MapReduceIndexerTool` for preparing Solr index offline. 
Following is the execution environment:

- Hadoop 2.7.3
- Zookeeper-3.4.6
- Solr-5.5.0
- Java 1.7.0_151

While executing the tool jar, I am getting the below error:

```
hduser@localhost:/usr/local/solr-5.5.0$ hadoop --config /etc/hadoop/conf jar /usr/local/solr-5.5.0/dist/solr-map-reduce-*.jar -D 'mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx500m' --morphline-file /home/hduser/simpl-morphline.conf --zk-host localhost:2181 --output-dir hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/data/output --collection myCollection --log4j ./log4j.properties --verbose "hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/data/input/simple.tsv"

`2487 [pool-6-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig  - Loading container configuration from /usr/local/solr-5.5.0/file:/tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1509433903085/9e6783da-03f6-41ba-9d4d-dcf8f267f6c6.solr.zip/solr.xml
12498 [Thread-64] INFO  org.apache.solr.hadoop.HeartBeater  - HeartBeat thread running
12499 [Thread-64] INFO  org.apache.solr.hadoop.HeartBeater  - heartbeat skipped count 0
12520 [Thread-22] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - job_local1445675116_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize record writer for org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool/MorphlineMapper, attempt_local1445675116_0001_r_000000_0
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize record writer for org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool/MorphlineMapper, attempt_local1445675116_0001_r_000000_0
at org.apache.solr.hadoop.SolrRecordWriter.<init>(SolrRecordWriter.java:128)
at org.apache.solr.hadoop.SolrOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SolrOutputFormat.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:540)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:614)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: solr.xml does not exist in /usr/local/solr-5.5.0/file:/tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1509433903085/9e6783da-03f6-41ba-9d4d-dcf8f267f6c6.solr.zip cannot start Solr
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromFile(SolrXmlConfig.java:106)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromSolrHome(SolrXmlConfig.java:139)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.<init>(CoreContainer.java:183)
at org.apache.solr.hadoop.SolrRecordWriter.createEmbeddedSolrServer(SolrRecordWriter.java:161)
at org.apache.solr.hadoop.SolrRecordWriter.<init>(SolrRecordWriter.java:121)
... 10 more
13339 [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool  - Job failed! jobName: org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool/MorphlineMapper, jobId: job_local1445675116_0001`
```

It is complaining for solr.xml, even if the solr.xml is available within the zookeeper configuration.

Comment: I didn't think Solr used Zookeeper unless it's in Solrcloud mode. The output here says nothing about connecting to Zookeeper

Comment: Yes, I am running solr in Solrcloud mode with embedded zookeeper.

Comment: Well, the SolrCloud mode is not enabled or setup then, since the file & config is trying to be read from the filesystem, not Zookeeper

Comment: I debug the MRIT jar - solr-map-reduce-5.5.0.jar in eclipse and notice the problem is happening at a place where it is converting hadoop Path (org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in to unix path(java.nio.file.Path):

Comment: The fact that `SolrXmlConfig.fromSolrHome` is being executed says to me its not making use of Zookeeper, and you should put your Solr xml in that folder

Comment: I have the following logs prior to the exception I posted in the main query. Here it is reading from the zookeeper config -

Comment: By the way, even here says to copy Solr xml into the solr home folder. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/getting-started-with-solrcloud.html

Comment: Following are logs where it is reading from the zookeeper config - following logs shows its connected to zookeeper -                                   
2185 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager  - Client is connected to ZooKeeper
2185 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient  - Using default ZkACLProvider
2187 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.hadoop.ZooKeeperInspector  - Load collection config from:/collections/myCollection
2243 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkConfigManager  - Writing file /tmp/1509433901532-0/solrconfig.xml

Comment: As that link says, *You either need to copy solr.xml to the solr_home directory, or keep in centrally in ZooKeeper /solr.xml.*